# Running a bash script from php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I have a raspberry pi connected to relay that switches lights.
To switch the relay i use two bash scripts:

*lighton.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 24 > /sys/class/gpio/export
gpio export 24 out
```

and *lightoff.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 24 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

When I execute scripts from console it works perfect, but...
When I try to execute them from web interface, only "*lighton.sh*" script works. Actually I have more scripts that I want to run but the only one working script is "*lighton.sh*".
This is the code of *index.php*:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['lightOn'] ) )
{
    exec ('bash /absolute-path-to-script/lighton.sh');
}

if( isset( $_POST['lightOff'] ) )
{
    exec ('bash /absolute-path-to-script/lightoff.sh');
}
?> 

<form method="POST">
    <input name="lightOn" type="submit" value="Turn ON" />
    <input name="lightOff" type="submit" value="Turn OFF" />
</form>
```

I dont know why the only one script is working.

UPD: I have put buttons in different forms, but it still doesn't work.
Sorry, i had a mistake in "codepasting" while i was writing this post(already corrected), but initial code is ok. So the problem is still actual.

UPD2: I have noticed that even if I put only one another button like:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['lightOn'] ) )
{
    exec ('bash /absolute-path-to-script/lightoff.sh');
}
?> 

<form method="POST">
    <input name="lightOff" type="submit" value="Turn OFF" />
</form>
```

the button still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: put those in two separate forms.... one form for off and another for on

Comment: Looks like a simple misspelling. Your script is named `lightoff.sh` but you try to run `ligthoff.sh` (`t` and `h` is swapped). `ligthon.sh` works because it's spelled wrong both places.